# how to scale divs when i minimize browser so that divs dont collapse over each other

Tags: html, scale

i have small question. 
how is it possible to set the heights of 2 divs so that they dont collapse but rather scale dynamically if i minimize the window? i did this in js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var footer = document.getElementById('footer').offsetHeight;
    var sidebar = document.getElementById('sidebar').offsetHeight;
    document.getElementById('sidebar').style.height = sidebar - footer + 'px';

});
```

this is working but not when i minimize, do i have to do it in a function and call it during window.load or so? the problem now is that when i minimize the browser, the divs are going over each other again..

thanks

Comment: minimize the window as in windows minimize to taskbar ? or resize to 'minimum size' ?

Comment: i minimize the window(browser) by clicking 'minimize' button of a browser. and i want that divs should stay as they do when the window is fully open. but now when i minimize the window, one div is covering other one. Concrete: my sidebar is covering my footer when window is minimized. i dont want it. i want that no matter how i scale the window, the sidebar should stay with some distance over footer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to bind to the resize event

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var sidebar = document.getElementById('sidebar').offsetHeight;
  $(window).resize(function(){
    var footer = document.getElementById('footer').offsetHeight;
    document.getElementById('sidebar').style.height = sidebar - footer + 'px';
  });
});
```

Comment: this looks good, but thru this i have another problem in the code. so it means now that everytimes the window is drawn, it will set the height again. now if i resize 2 times, the sidebar is getting twice smaller. :)).

Comment: That's because you use sidebar in your calculations on each resize. Updated code in the sample. Still not sure if it is what you want, but I am sure you can find out how to get it work now that you have the resize

Comment: yeah but it should resize the sidebar each time, any idea where the bug is? :(.

Comment: the footer is contant number, thats why it is substracting each time the same amount thats why it is getting smaller on each resize... i am thinking...

Comment: Do you need to footer to be fixed?

Comment: i think, on each resize i will set the bottom margin of sidebar to footer height, right?. then it will stay on each resize..

Comment: that would be better I think... right now you decrease the sidebar size too fast (take a look here http://ryanfait.com/resources/footer-stick-to-bottom-of-page/) for fixed footer ... it may give you some idea's

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution also for those who once search for this kind of setup...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
     var winh = document.body.clientHeight;
     var footer = document.getElementById('footer').offsetHeight;
     document.getElementById('sidebar').style.height = winh - 5/2*footer + 'px';
     document.getElementById('sidebar').style.marginBottom = footer + 'px';
$(window).resize(function(){
     var winh = document.body.clientHeight;
     var footer = document.getElementById('footer').offsetHeight;
     document.getElementById('sidebar').style.height = winh - 5/2*footer + 'px';
     document.getElementById('sidebar').style.marginBottom = footer + 'px';
     });
});
</script>
```

this code sets the height of sidebar dynamically, both during document.ready and also during resize. special thanks to Bart for help!