# Stuck with simple Javascript function to find height

Tags: javascript, find, height

Anybody knows why the following code fails to work? I need a dynamic height for a fixed width div that may descend below past the viewport.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
function findheight(){  
  var div = document.getElementById('bg');
  var height = document.scrollHeight;
  div.style.height = height + 'px';
}

  </script>     
</head>

<body onload="findheight()">
    <div id="bg">
```

Is there another way around this if not??  Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: give alert(height) above div.style.height = height + 'px'; and see Whether u r getting height?

Comment: Thanks, no I'm not getting anything...

Comment: @kritya : IMO, one does not need to use a library for simple tasks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could achieve this using javascript, you have to use the 'offsetHeight' method.

```
function getHeight() {
    var height = document.getElementById('test').offsetHeight;
    alert(height);
}
```

Here is a sample [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qwL6z/)
You can find the details [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.offsetHeight)

Answer (score 0):

The reason why this is not working is because the div.style.height is
empty therefore doing parseFloat returns NaN

`document.getElementById('bg').offsetHeight` then this should work.

**or**
try

```
function bodyHeight() {
var scnHei;

if (self.innerHeight) // all except Explorer
{
    scnHei = self.innerHeight;
}
else if (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.clientHeight)
    // Explorer 6 Strict Mode
{
    scnHei = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
}
else if (document.body) // other Explorers
{
    scnHei = document.body.clientHeight;
}

document.getElementById("bgr_right").style.height=scnHei + "px";
document.getElementById("bgr_left").style.height=scnHei + "px";
}
```

in you body  `onload=bodyHeight();`

Answer (score 0):

here is my solution for this kind of problem. hope this works for you too..

[how to scale divs when i minimize browser so that divs dont collapse over each other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10967143/how-to-scale-divs-when-i-minimize-browser-so-that-divs-dont-collapse-over-each-o/10967192#comment14320087_10967192)

use `$(document).height()` from jquery to get document height